# How are <SimpleForm> and <TabbedForm> in react-admin injecting resource prop to Input components automatically?

Tags: react-admin

Unfortunately I could not find an explainaition in the docs how are these thing working and I am new to React so struggling to understand what's happening.

How is this magic working and where to find it in the source is the magic hidden?

Is this a common patter in React libraries or is it a special thing which react-admin does?

Why they do not inject the resource prop in other components?

Answer (score 0):

They use React's `cloneElement` throughout react-admin to clone a child component, and then this method also allows to inject props. 
So for instance in an iterator component like `Datagrid` they will map over all records, and then clone the child for each record, and insert a `record` prop for that iteration.
It's also why some components (input & field components) need to be direct children of the iterator component so there can be no other component in between (such as a Material-UI `Grid` component for layout) since then the injected props are lost.